# Как залогиниться в SOAP сервисе?

Tags: php, soap

Имеется структура запроса:

Имеется структура запроса:

```
POST https://хххххх&WSSOAP=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "document/http://ххххх:testStatus"
Content-Length: 572
Host: xxxxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="nameSpace">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <UsernameToken xmlns="http://xxxxxx">Login</UsernameToken>
      <PasswordText xmlns="http://xxxxxx">Password</PasswordText>
      <SessionType xmlns="http://xxxxxx">Session</SessionType>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:testStatus_Input>
         <ws:statId>xxxxxx</ws:statId>
      </ws:testStatus_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Требуется с этими данными залогиниться в сервисе.

Подключаю wsdl:

```
$client = new SoapClient("wsdl.wsdl", Array("exceptions"=>0,"trace" => 1));
```

Формирую хедер:

```
$headerbody = array('UsernameToken' => 'Login',
                    'PasswordText' => 'Password');
$header = new SOAPHeader('nameSpace', 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);       
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Вызываю метод:

```
$result = $client->testStatus(array("statId"=>"xxxxxx"));
echo $result;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> "SoapFault exception:
> [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error Code: 10944642
> Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP
> Message - Session Token is missing or
> invalid or has expired in
> /var/www/хххх:15 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/хххххх(15):
> SoapClient->__call('testStatus',
> Array) #1 /var/www/xxxxx(15):
> SoapClient->testStatus(Array) #2
> {main}".

Не могу понять, проблема в том, что не получается залогиниться? Ведь токен и пароль верные, или как-то не правильно обращаюсь к сервису?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97273) снипет, вероятно вы не совсем правильно генерите заголовки.

Comment: Переписал, всё-равно ошибка:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error Code: 10944642 Error Message: Error: Inbound SOAP Message - Session Token is missing or invalid or has expired in /var/www/bua/admin/application_status/index.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/bua/admin/application_status/index.php(52): SoapClient->__soapCall('checkOptyStatus', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/bua/admin/application_status/index.php on line 52 

Вот непонятно, проблема с отправкой запроса или у них на серваке?

Comment: А как можно просмотреть отправляемый заголовок?
Пробую так:

echo $objClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();

но он отработать должен только после вызова метода, а при вызове метода - вышеуказанная ошибка и далее скрипт падает, не доходит до этой функции.